# Jquery: Getting values from textboxes created asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok since the question was not clear i have updated it as below:

I am uploading a CSV file to the server, it parses the csv and get the values of the Amount column and then prepares a html containing the textboxes with the amount. This html generated is then passed to javascript, which outputs the complete html containing textboxes with values.

Server Code that returns html via an ajax call:

```
foreach($amounts as $val){ 
    $html .+ '<input type="text" class="inputText" value="'.$val['amount'].'"/>';
}
echo $html;
```

Jquery code that outputs the html (inside `generateHtml()` function):

```
$('#amtblock').html(html);
```

html that results:

```
<div id="amtblock">
    <input type="text" class="inputText" value="3"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" value="78"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" value="12"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" value="21"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" value="89"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" value="22"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" value="222"/>
</div>
```

Now when i try to get all the textbox values by this code (inside a `calculateAmount()` function):

```
$('.inputText').each(function() {
    total += Number($(this).val());     
});
```

`total` is not printed in above code. I want to calculate the total and show it.
How can i get and set values to elements I've created dynamically?

Comment: When and how do you generate the textboxes?

Comment: Need to see more of your code.

Comment: If they're "not registered with DOM" where are they? Are you trying to say that they're not part of the original html, but they're added dynamically?

Comment: P.S. Do you declare `total` before the loop? If not your code would crash with a reference error when you try to say `total += ...` (a problem that has nothing to do with whether the elements in question are added dynamically).

Comment: if youre adding textAreas instead of textInputs you must use .text() instead of .val()

Comment: @johnSmith - That's not true. `.val()` works on `<textarea>` elements.

Comment: @all - I have added more details. Hope its clear now. Thanks guys!!

Comment: Is the `'#amtblock'` element in the DOM? If so all of the inputs will be too once you add them with `$('#amtblock').html(html);`. You never answered my previous question about whether `total` is declared before you try to use it in the loop...

Comment: I see `$html` declared in the PHP, but where is `html` declared in the JS?

Comment: @DerekHenderson - i have not showed it in hurry but its coming as ajax response

Comment: @VishwaKumar, there are two possible problems:  (1) your totaling function comes before you html-inserting function, or (2) you have not declare `var total = 0;`.  I can't think of anything else it might be.

Comment: Further to @DerekHenderson's last comment, option (1a) You aren't allowing for async processing in your Ajax.

Comment: @DerekHenderson - Ya you were right. I was calling the generateHtml() and calculateAmount() functions on page load together. I moved calculateAmount() into the generateHtml() function and it worked. Thanks. Could you please write it as answer so that i can select it.

Comment: @VishwaKumar, I posted it as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create elements with an AJAX call, remember that they are created asynchronously.  That means that functions fired after the AJAX call will be fired before the AJAX call is complete.

In order to take into account DOM elements created from an AJAX call, you have to wait until the call is complete.

In your case, you need to make sure that your `calculateAmount()` function is fired after your inputs are created.  You can do this by putting `calculateAmount()` inside the `generateHtml()` function after `$('#amtblock').html(html);`.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for editing, I hadn't seen all the code yet, this should work for you

```
total=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  total=0;
  $('.inputText').each(function() {
      val_to_add=$(this).val() || 0
      total += parseInt(val_to_add);     
      console.log(total);
   });
});
```

Try it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ugwx5/2/

Comment: Why would he need to create a div?  What is the `input` event??

Comment: nothing I just didn't use console.log I am putting the total into a div I'll replace the final line.

Comment: But this adds to the total only the value from the element the event applied to, and if that event occurred several times in a row for the same element each new value would get added in - as compared to the OP's code which tried to loop over the items once.

Comment: There is still no 'input' event I have ever heard of.  Care to provide some documentation showing that this would work?

Comment: @DerekHenderson - The [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/input) is real, but it isn't going to help with the OP's problem. Also, CodeBird, why did you introduce `parseInt()`? It doesn't do the same thing as `Number()` (and you _really_ should specify the radix in the second parameter when using `parseInt()` on user-entered data).

Comment: @nnnnnn, thank you for that.  I learned something new today.  ;)  And, yes, the input event won't help as it is essentially a change event.

Comment: eh understood, so basically this: $('.inputText').on("input", function(){ could be replace by $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: @CodeBird, no.  Triggering the count on an event is not what the OP is looking for, so that part of your answer is wrong.  And we can probably assume this is already in a document ready function.  We just don't have enough information from the OP to answer the question correctly yet.  Each of your edits is resulting in more and more convoluted code, where the answer is most likely something very simple to do with either (1) the order code is processed or (2) variable declarations.